# In Redux, is there the concept of Data Provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Basically I want to implement an architecture of the type

```
UserManager.getUser(22)
```

getUser() -> ReduxStore -> (Does not contain an user with ID 22) -> Goes to User Provider -> User Provider goes to API and returns User object.
Redux Store then saves for subsequent requests and returns User object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux has [unidirectional data flow](https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow/), so the writing and the reading of data are decoupled.

Components read Redux data by subscribing to the store via `connect` or `useSelector`, and they write data via `disptach`ing actions in the store.

A selector takes in state and returns a subset of the state, but it does not change the state. A dispatched action can change the state, but it does not return any state.

[CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) is one of the [motivations behind Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation/). The idea of CQRS is basically to:

> use a different model to update information than the model you use to read information

In Redux the update-model is the actions and the read-model is the selectors. To combine them into a single "provider" would be to defeat the purpose of Redux's design.

But if you absolutely had to conflate the two concerns, it might be possible to somehow combine a selector and action-dispatch with a thunk. Again, though, it would not be idiomatic Redux.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we call them action creators. Let's say you're using redux thunk for side effects so `getUser` will be an action creator that'll first query redux store to see if there is data available if not it'll fetch it from server and store in the redux store like this:

```js
function getUser(id) {
  // getState is a function that gives us access to entire redux store
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      let user = getState().users.find(x => x.id === id) || null;
      if (user) {
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER', payload: user })
        return;
      }

      user = fetchUserFromServer(id);
      dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER', payload: user })
    } catch(error) {
      // handle error here
    }
  }
}
```

Now when next time `getUser` is called there will be data for that user in the redux store and a call to server will be avoided.

Hope it helps :)